# Query to get exact matches of Elastic Field with multile values in Array

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I want to write a query in Elastic that applies a filter based on values i have in an array (in my R program). Essentially the query:

1. Matches a time range (time field in Elastic)
2. Matches "trackId" field in Elastic to any value in array oth_usr
3. Return 2 fields - "trackId", "propertyId"

I have the following primitive version of the query but do not know how to use the oth_usr array in a query (part 2 above).

```
query <- sprintf('{"query":{"range":{"time":{"gte":"%s","lte":"%s"}}}}',start_date,end_date)
view_list <- elastic::Search(index = "organised_recent",type = "PROPERTY_VIEW",size = 10000000,
                             body=query, fields = c("trackId", "propertyId"))$hits$hits
```

Comment: I don't know if I should try to answer, just give clues, or ignore this question. did you try anything  ? Try reading [ask] and [mcve] please and complete your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `terms` query and embed it as well as the `range` one into a `bool/must` query. Try updating your query like this:

```
terms <- paste(sprintf("\"%s\"", oth_usr), collapse=", ")
query <- sprintf('{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms": {"trackId": [%s]}},{"range": {"time": {"gte": "%s","lte": "%s"}}}]}}}',terms,start_date,end_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However when I run it I get: Error in check_inputs(body) : parse error: trailing garbage
          lte": "1444069800000"}}}]}}} {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"ter
                     (right here) ------^ The pointer points to beginning of this ->{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"ter

Comment: Try again please, I might have missed square brackets in the `terms` query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent in R syntax, but this is raw JSON query that works.

It checks whether your `time` field matches given range (`start_time` and `end_time`) and whether one of your `terms` exact matches `trackId`.

It returns only `trackId`, `propertyId` fields, as per your request:

```
POST /indice/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "trackId",
      "propertyId"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "start_time",
              "lte": "end_time"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "trackId": [
              "terms"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```